# Crackling sound in speaker

Tags: apt, audio, pulseaudio, pop-os

I am currently using pop 22.04 and while I  was playing a video suddenly my left side speaker started to make a crackling sound and noise while playing the video. I have test that only my left side speaker has a problem.
I have tried solving this by going to audio troubleshooting of system76 :-
[enter link description here](https://support.system76.com/articles/audio/)

While trying solutions, there was one command which my laptop showed error but it was for restarting something which I don't know and it also showed the error when I was trying to install pulseaudio in my laptop :-

> sudo sed -i 's/load-module module-suspend-on-idle/#load-module module-suspend-on-idle/' /etc/pulse/default.pa

So,please can anyone tell me solution for this problem and my initial problem is not solved yet. And I am attaching the screen of showing error .
[image]

Comment: Regarding your first problem as worded in the title, did you ensure it is not an hardware (wiring) problem ? Your second problem is unrelated however, why would you want to install pulseaudio since you seem having pipewire already installed. (both packages actually conflict)

Comment: yes i do not use any wiring it's just my laptop and if u r talking about inside laptop wiring then i don't know